# general statement present continuous in relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses, present-continuous, present-simple

Along the lines of my first question "[Past tense in relative clauses to describe facts and general truth](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/314394/past-tense-in-relative-clauses-to-describe-facts-and-general-truth)", I have a second question about tenses in relative clauses when talking about general things/ ideas/ statements.

Supposing, somebody asks me if I am a tidy person and I want to answer that some people might think that I am tidy and other people might think the opposite. It just depends on whether the other person is very tidy or not. What should I answer?:

```
1) It depends on the person who is judging.
vs
2) It depends on the person who judges.
```

I believe the first sentence should be correct because the relative clause describes a person in one single moment. The second sentence sounds wrong to me because "who judges" sounds like a clause to describe somebody whose task/ habit/... it is to judge. On the other hand, present continuous is normally used for things that happen during the time of speaking and here it's just a thought and not a current situation (the same problem: should it be "used for things that are happening during the time of speaking" or "used for things that happen during the time of speaking") My general problem is, that I'm always unsure which tense I should use when talking about "theoretical" situations.

Thanks a lot in advance.